# How to Display Error Codes sample wcf service?

Tags: wcf

i need to write the error as:

Error Codes:

```
101: Syntax Error 
102: id already exists 
103: User already exists 
104: Unsupported id
105: Server Error, try again or contact administrator
```

Please tell me sample rest wcf service on that...
i am new to write the wcf services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***IServce1.cs***

```
[ServiceConstract]
public interface IService1
{
  [OperationContract]
  string GetErrorCode(int er);
}
```

***Service1.svc.cs***

```
public class Service1:IService1
{
  public string GetErrorCode(int er)
  {
     string description;
     switch(er)
     {
        case 101: description="Syntax Error"; break;
        case 102: description="ID already exists"; break;
        case 103: description="User already exists"; break;
        case 104: description="Unsupported ID"; break;
        case 105: description="Server Error, try again or contact administrator"; break;
        default: //Write whatever you want to throw to user.
      }
     return description;
  } 
}
```

---

Use this in your client application with another method wherever you presume the error will occur in a try/catch block but before that create your own custom exception and associate each of the code with it or also you can store these in a database table and then using an ID can throw the appropriate error with the code from there.

Comment: How to check all these in code if all are true need to display the result.any simple sample for custom error handling.......

Comment: consider the cases as fall through instead of break. And moreover if you are writing the custom -{throw new exception}  for each of these codes, then you would be assigning only one code for each exception.So, in case all are thrown, it will be throwing all the 'description' whenever it encounters the exception.

Comment: Also,to make it look better,consider writing all these exceptions in a separate class and using the switch case inside this class,so that it doesnt mess up your actual code where you are using try/catch :)

Comment: Have look at this link for creating custom exceptions in c#: http://csharptutorial.blogspot.in/2006/05/custom-exceptions.html

Answer (score 1):

Build a class (call it YourErrorClass for simplicity here) with an integer property (ID) and String property (Description)

Decorate that with DataContract

Then in your web service itself, throw a FaultException with the values appropriately issued.

When you do this, make sure where you capture them you display the values accordingly to the user.

Comment: And remember to decorate the service with [FaultContractAttribute]

Comment: Any samples for that please let me know.